# Using Regex to parse a URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, uri

I'm currently using Modenizr to determine what link to serve users based on their device of choice. So if they're using a mobile device I want to return a URI if not then just return a traditional URL.

**URI:** `spotify:album:1jcYwZsN7JEve9xsq9BuUX`

**URL:** `https://open.spotify.com/album/1jcYwZsN7JEve9xsq9BuUX`

Right now I'm using `slice()` to retrieve the last 22 characters of the URI. Though it works I'd like to parse the string via regex in the event that the URI exceeds the aforementioned character amount. What would be the best way to get the string of characters after the second colon of the URI?

```
$(".spotify").attr("href", function(index, value) {
  if (Modernizr.touch) {
    return value
  } else {
    return "https://open.spotify.com/album/" + value.slice(-22);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is appropriate for this task because it is quite simple, here's the RegEx which supports as many `:` as there are and will still work

```
/[\w\:]*\:(\w+)/
```

**How it works**

> `[\w\:]*` Will get all word characters (Letters, numbers, underscore) and colons
>
> `\:` Will basically tell the previous thing to stop at a colon. Regex is by default greedy, that means it will get the last colon
>
> `(\w+)` Will select all word characters and store it in a group so we can access it

---

Use this like:

```
var string = 'spotify:album:1jcYwZsN7JEve9xsq9BuUX',
    parseduri = string.match(/[\w\:]*\:(\w+)/)[1];
```

`parseduri` is the result

---

And then you can finally combine this:

```
var url = 'https://open.spotify.com/album/'+parseduri;
```

Comment: What does the `[1]` at the end represent?

Comment: @CarlEdwards RegEx returns an array `["spotify:album:1jcYwZsN7JEve9xsq9BuUX", "1jcYwZsN7JEve9xsq9BuUX"]`, so `[1]` is used to select the correct item in the array. Arrays start at 0

Comment: Is it required for this example being that `string` stands alone as one string versus and array of URIs? Interestingly I took the `[1]` off and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would like something like this using split.

```
var url = 'spotify:album:1jcYwZsN7JEve9xsq9BuUX'.split(':');    
var part = url[url.length-1];
// alert(part);

return "https://open.spotify.com/album/" + part;
```